# How to log and intercept all database operations using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have the flowing transaction code :

```
 using (var context = new StDbContext())
         {
            context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
            if (!context.Database.Connection.State.HasFlag(ConnectionState.Open))
            {
               context.Database.Connection.OpenAsync();
            }
            using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
               try
               {
                  var unit_of_work = new UnitOfWork(context);
                  unit_of_work.Sessions.AddModelSession(Model, unit_of_work);
                  context.SaveChanges();

                  transaction.Commit();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                  transaction.Rollback();
                  TestBaseCore.mNLogLoggerService.Error(ex.Message);
               }

            }
         }
```

Inside `unit_of_work.Sessions.AddModelSession();` I'm saving data for different tables `(UnitOfWork.Project.AddProject()`; .... `UnitOfWork.Fixture.AddFixture()` ..and so on)->but sometimes the code is crashing in `unit_of_work.Sessions.AddModelSession();' and I'm not able to catch any exception using try catch? 
**Is there a way to log in a log file all the database operations** to be able to figure it out whats the real issue there?

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and that code is bad. You catch exception but only log the message. There are two articles on the mater I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET | It is possible taht logging code is not working reliably, especially in Exception cases. I hope it is not tryting to write the stuff to a Database or freshly opening the logfiles - loging should only go to files. And those should be kept open the entire runtime.

Comment: Ty  @Christopher , can you be more specific about "hat code is bad"? I'm trying to find a better and safer approach for it? the strange thing is  that is working when saving data to a local mysql database...but is crashing when I'm trying to save data to a mysql database hosted by amazon rds...and the only difference between the logic is the connection string(even in debug the code is just exiting )

Comment: The connection string is a big difference. Propably the biggest one possible. Those strings are their own topic, with a special webpage just for it: https://www.connectionstrings.com/